# Get choices from a DataBase query in wtforms and flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm developing a web app using Flask, SQLAlchemy and WTForms. I would like to get my choices in a **SelectField** from a query through my DB.

With more details.

```
my_query = my_table.query.with_entities(My_Entities).all()
```

**Result**

> [(u'1',), (u'2',), (u'3',)]

My class

```
class MyForm(Form):
    My_Var = SelectField(choices=RIGHT_HERE)
```

Is there any way ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this situation what you can do is use the extensions that are in WTForms. What you do is import the `QuerySelectField` that you need:

`from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField`

Then you create a function that will query the database and return the stuff you need:

```
def skill_level_choices():      
    return db.session.query(SkillLevel).all()
```

After you have the query object you can place it into your `QuerySelectField` by using the `query_factory` parameter

```
skill_level = QuerySelectField(u'Skill level',      
                               validators=[Required()],
                               query_factory=skill_level_choices)
```

Comment: Is this under forms.py?

Comment: @m1yag1 : So the code need to be included in `class MyForm(Form)`? Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to just query objects and place them as choices in a select field. Which field is the label? Which is the value?

Comment: This is using a QuerySelectField so it does it for you. If you were to use the stock SelectField then you would need to pass in tuple pairs of the label and value to choices. That is why it is called a query_factory.

Comment: You can also use the `get_label` parameter in `QuerySelectField` to display a certain field, and alternatively `QuerySelectMultipleField` for multiple rows

Comment: 2024 update: be sure you have `wtforms-sqlalchemy` installed or `pip install -U wtforms-sqlalchemy`. The import is `from wtforms_sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField`.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**

I had quite simmilar problem with `wtforms` and `peewee`, and here is my workaround

```
class MyForm(FlaskForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.my_select_field.choices = [
            (el.id, el.description) for el in MyModel.select()
        ]

    my_select_field = SelectField("Field", coerce=int)
```

**Explanation:**

We modified original `FlaskForm`, so that it executs database query each time when it is being created.

So `MyForm` data choices stays up to date.

Answer (score 1):

Populate QuerySelectField with values from Database

```
from wtforms.ext.sqlalchemy.fields import QuerySelectField

from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
name=QuerySelectField('Name',query_factory=lambda:my_table.query,get_label="username")
```

Comment: Hi @jobinv12! I think this answer could be improved by adding a short description of what the code does and how it does it.

Answer (score 0):

```
options = SelectField('optionName', default='None', choices=[(option.name, option.name) for option in Options.query.all()])
```

Where Options is the db.Model.