# WTForm SelectField with values from database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I want to extract values ​​from the database and substitute them into the SelectField, but I get such an error. What am I doing wrong?

I tried the QuerySelectField, but as I understand it, I can not get the project value from there

forms.py

```
class SelectProjectForm(FlaskForm):
    project_choices = [(projects.id, projects.project) for projects in Projects.query.all()]
    project_select = SelectField("Project", choices=project_choices)
```

models.py

```
class Projects(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    project = db.Column(db.String(255), unique=True, nullable=False)
```

views.py

```
@main_blueprint.route("/")
def home():
    select_project = SelectProjectForm()
    return render_template("main/home.html",
                           select_project=select_project)
```

error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1030, in __call__
    return self.registry[key]
KeyError: 4504378816

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    app = create_app()
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/accesses/project/server/__init__.py", line 49, in create_app
    from project.server.main.views import main_blueprint
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/accesses/project/server/main/views.py", line 8, in <module>
    from project.server.main.forms import AddressForm, AppForm, SelectAddrForm, SelectAppForm, SelectProjectForm, AccessName, CreateProject
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/accesses/project/server/main/forms.py", line 35, in <module>
    class SelectProjectForm(FlaskForm):
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/accesses/project/server/main/forms.py", line 36, in SelectProjectForm
    project_choices = [(projects.id, projects.project) for projects in Projects.query.all()]
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 519, in __get__
    return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
    return self.registry()
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 1032, in __call__
    return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 3254, in __call__
    return self.class_(**local_kw)
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 136, in __init__
    self.app = app = db.get_app()
  File "/Users/davidamb/adv_it_flask_deploy_aws/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 982, in get_app
    'No application found. Either work inside a view function or push'
RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. See http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/contexts/.
```

Thx for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314102/get-choices-from-a-database-query-in-wtforms-and-flask-sqlalchemy, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52635661/dynamically-populate-wtform-selectfield-with-sqlalchemy-query, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59688319/flask-wtforms-queryselectfield-runtimeerror

Comment: @IljaEverilä QuerySelectField doesn't suit me because I will need to pull out the project value

Comment: For what purpose? Display? You would use `get_label`: "Specify get_label to customize the label associated with each option. If a string, this is the name of an attribute on the model object to use as the label text. If a one-argument callable, this callable will be passed model instance and expected to return the label text."

Comment: @IljaEverilä not for display, I want to send the selected value to another database

Comment: Does that happen from the client or on the server? Since `Projects.project` is unique, you could override the option value with `get_pk`, I think: "alternately pass a one-argument callable to get_pk which can return a unique comparable key." The reason why I was/am confused is that according to documentation `SelectField` choices is a list of `(value, label)` tuples and so you use `Projects.id` as the value in your existing attempt, not `Projects.project`.

Comment: @IljaEverilä server

Comment: Are you then trying to avoid having to do the reverse DB lookup on the server, when user submits a selected project? Do you otherwise validate that the sent project exists?